# MySQL Query Optimization - Indexes & Joins 12 million+ records

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT
    `track_title`.`title`,
    `track`.`id`,
    `artist`.`name` artist,
    `album`.`title` album,
    `st_tag`.`tag`,
    `track`.`year`
FROM 
    `track`
JOIN `artist` ON `track`.`artist_id` = `artist`.`id`
JOIN `album` ON `track`.`album_id` = `album`.`id`
JOIN `track_title` ON `track`.`id` = `track_title`.`id`
JOIN `track_tags` ON `track`.`id` = `track_tags`.`track_id`
JOIN `st_tag` ON `track_tags`.`tag_id` = `st_tag`.`id`
WHERE
    `track_title`.`title_sch` LIKE "% love %"
ORDER BY
    `track_title`.`title`
LIMIT
    0,500;
```

Right now it takes at least 15 mins to execute. Both track and track_title have about 12 million records. Album and artist have at least a million each. Can this be sped up with better indexes? I've been playing with a combination of indexes in order to speed up the queries but i'm still having trouble getting it right.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `album` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(1000) default NULL,
  `title_sch` varchar(1000) default NULL,
  `flags` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `title_sch` (`title_sch`(255)),
  KEY `album_title` USING BTREE (`title`(255)),
  KEY `album_cluster` USING BTREE (`id`,`title`(255),`title_sch`(255))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `artist` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(1000) default NULL,
  `name_sch` varchar(1000) default NULL,
  `flags` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `name_sch` (`name_sch`(255)),
  KEY `name` USING BTREE (`name`(255)),
  KEY `artist_name` USING BTREE (`name`(255)),
  KEY `artist_cluster` USING BTREE (`id`,`name`(255),`name_sch`(255))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `st_tag` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `tag` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `genre` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `parent` smallint(5) unsigned default NULL,
  `depth` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `display` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '-1',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=352 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `track` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `artist_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `album_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `flags` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `year` smallint(5) unsigned default NULL,
  `duration` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `track_no` smallint(5) unsigned default NULL,
  `disc_no` tinyint(3) unsigned default NULL,
  `explicit` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `popularity` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `album_id` (`album_id`),
  KEY `artist_id` (`artist_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `track_tags` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `track_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `track_id` (`track_id`),
  KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26661380 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `track_title` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(1000) default NULL,
  `title_sch` varchar(1000) default NULL,
  `version` varchar(100) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `title` (`title`(255)),
  KEY `title_sch` (`title_sch`(255)),
  KEY `title_cluster` USING BTREE (`id`,`title`(255),`title_sch`(255))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**EDIT**

The server i'm running on has about 4gbs of ram.

Querying without the first % definitely speeds up the query. It runs in 4 secs approximately. However, that doesn't give me the results i need because I need all titles with the word "love" in it not just ones that start with love. What do you guys think about this? I have a title_sch field in the track_title table. That field is a normalized version of the title where any punctuation has been removed, title has been changed to lowercase etc. Basically a field where the title has been cured. I was thinking what if i move the regular title back to the tracks table and make to track_title table a one to many relationship from track to track_title. But i would change track_title to have one word entry per word pertaining to each track. I know this will increase the table size tremendously but i then i can index track_title.title_sch and instead of using like I can use "=" right? Or when the user searches "love hurts" i can do use "IN" instead. What do you guys think? I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: What are the indexes you have tried? Can you post the table create scripts?

Comment: @SebastianMeine added the table structure with the indexes.

Comment: Can you post the hardware and mysql config? Can it be you run out of memory / buffer space and it then hits a dead slow consumer level / cheap virtual level disc that is dead slow? If oyu do large joins, you NEED enough RAM and a decent disc subsystem (cheap these days - just get a SSD) because this is where you waste performance, index or not. And the Like % really kills index use. No wildcards at the start, please.

Comment: Please see me edit. I thought of an alternative but I'm open to any suggestions other than the wildcard at the start.

Answer (score 2):

With the disclaimer that I'm not specifically a MySQL expert:

My guess is that either it's failing to whittle down the huge number of rows that result from such as huge join, or it can't index the title well because the LIKE starts with a wildcard.

Testing the second is easy, see if it runs better without a leading wildcard. If this is the case we can look for solutions.

For the first (and potentially the second as well), I would suggest breaking it up by doing a smaller join into a temporary table, then joining that with the other tables.

For example, if we can assume that there are foreign rows in all tables for a given track, we can SELECT, ORDER and LIMIT based on track_title alone into a temporary table. Then join in all the other tables.

Comment: Yes, LIKE "% love %" takes out any index usage for that - and likely we talök also of too little ram and pathetic disc, which means the data is not there (in memory) and slow to get (from disc). Result is slow query.

Comment: Definitely does speed up without the first %. Please see me edited question and let me know what you think.

Comment: It's hard for me to weigh up the costs and benefits of your suggested solution when we're talking about that many rows. Make sure you don't denormalise too much, e.g. maybe add a track_word table to avoid repeating the full track title. Also I still think it's worth trying my suggestion with temporary tables.

Comment: that's what i meant. just used the same name. so track_title field without normalization would go in the track table and the track_title table would become track_word and it'll be just an id with one word for example. {id => 10929909, word => "and"}, {id => 10929909, word => "i"}, {id => 10929909, word => "love"}, {id => 10929909, word => "her"} etc...

Comment: It's definitely worth a try. Let me know how it goes.